# Google translate in address bar

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I want to add google translator to my website.

Google brought me here:
https://translate.google.com/manager/website/add

Everything works fine, but the way how it is integrated is just ugly as you can see in this screenshot:
[image]

Now what i want is to show the translator plugin in the address bar like this: [image]

I can't find any documentation/tutorial which tells me how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the icon is showing in the address bar, then the feature has been added to **the browser** and not to the website.

This will be a browser extension which the user has installed.

Websites can't add content outside the viewport except in very limited ways (e.g. `<title>`).

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for your answer! So i have to integrate it the "ugly" way i guess^^